# Expectation of discrete random variables and absolute convergence.

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega$ be a countable sample space, $P$ a probability measure on $\Omega$, and $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables on $\Omega$ with $E(|X|),E(|Y|)<\infty$. Denote by $\{x_j\}$ and $\{y_k\}$, respectively, the sets of values taken by $X$ and $Y$. The book says that

> $$\sum_j\sum_k x_jy_kP(X=x_j)P(Y=y_k)=\left\{\sum_jx_jP(X=x_j)\right\}\{\left\{\sum_ky_kP(Y=y_k)\right\}$$
> by the absolute convergence of $\sum_j\sum_k x_jy_kP(X=x_j,Y=y_k)$.

But I think the convergence of $\sum_jx_jP(X=x_j)$ and $\sum_ky_kP(Y=y_k)$ suffices; for if $\sum a_n$ converges then so does $\sum ca_n$ and $\sum ca_n=c\sum a_n$. Since $x_jP(X=x_j)$ is constant relative to $k$,
$$\sum_j\sum_kx_jy_kP(X=x_j)P(Y=y_k)=\sum_j(x_jP(X=x_j)\sum_ky_kP(Y=y_k)\text{.}$$
Since $\sum_ky_kP(Y=y_k)$ is constant relative to $j$,
$$\sum_j(x_jP(X=x_j))\sum_ky_kP(Y=y_k)=(\sum_ky_kP(Y=y_k))\sum_jx_jP(X=x_j)\text{.}$$
Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, but,

I think what the book meant is, given the absolute convergence of $\sum_j \sum_k x_j y_k P(X = x_j, Y = y_k)$, we can write

$E[XY] = \sum_j \sum_k x_j y_k P(X = x_j, Y = y_k) = \{\sum_j x_j P(X = x_j) \} \{\sum_k y_k P(Y = y_k) \}$

This is true because the expectation can be defined only if the sum absolutely converges.

Here I assumed you are reading the proof of $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$. Am I  right?